# React - Need dropdown to select the correct option (option values for dropdown represented as string digits)

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-forms

I am trying to get my dropdown option to pre-select the correct value when I am updating my `friends`.  To give context about my code and what my issue is what is happening is on another component called `Friends`, I have friend cards rendered and each card has an update button. If you click that update button, the Route path changes to `"/AddFriend/{id}"` which causes my `AddFriend` component to render and then I make an ajax call (`getById`) in my `AddFriend` component  using the id that I passed it from my `Friends` component in order to get all the information about that specific friend and populate my form with that `friend`'s information. All my form input fields correctly populate with the correct `friend`'s information but my issue is the statusId which I have as a dropdown (not input field). Now I could change the `value` attributes on my option tag to reflect the value that it holds inside of it:

So if I changed my option tags from to look like `<option value="NotSet">NotSet</option>` instead of `<option value="1">NotSet</option>` that would cause my dropdown to select the correct value but my instructor said I need those values to be numbers (represented as strings).

So for example, let's say the `friend` who's edit button I clicked on had a `statusId` of `"Active"`, I want my application to know to that because my `statusId` is `"Active"` then my dropdown's selected value needs to be `<option value="2">Active</option>`.

```
    import React from "react";
    import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
    import * as FriendService from "../services/FriendService";
    
    class AddFriend extends React.Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                formData: {
                    title: "",
                    bio: "",
                    summary: "",
                    headline: "",
                    slug: "",
                    statusId: "",
                    skills: "",
                    primaryImage: ""
                }
            };
    
            this.onGetByIdSuccess = this.onGetByIdSuccess.bind(this);
            this.onGetByIdUpdateSuccess = this.onGetByIdSuccess.bind(this);
            this.onFormFieldChanged = this.onFormFieldChanged.bind(this);
        }
    
        onFormFieldChanged = (e) => {
            let currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
            let newValue = currentTarget.value;
            let inputName = currentTarget.name;
    
            console.log({currentTarget, newValue});
            
            this.setState(() => {
                let formData = {...this.state.formData};
                formData[inputName] = newValue;
                return {formData};
            });
        };
    
        onSubmitClicked = () => {
            const data = {...this.state.formData};
            let friendId = this.props.match.params.friendId;
            console.log(data);
            if(!friendId) {
                FriendService.add(data)
                    .then(this.onAddFriendSuccess)
                    .catch(this.onAddFriendError);
            }
            else {
                FriendService.update(friendId)
                    .then(this.onUpdateFriendSuccess)
                    .catch(this.onUpdateFriendError);
            }
        };
    
        onAddFriendSuccess(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    
        onAddFriendError(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    
        onUpdateFriendSuccess(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    
        onUpdateFriendError(err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
    
            let friendId = this.props.match.params.friendId;
            console.log("ComponentDidMount", {friendId});
    
            if(friendId){
    
                FriendService.getById(friendId)
                    .then(this.onGetByIdSuccess)
                    .catch(this.onGetByIdError);
            }
        }
    
        onGetByIdSuccess(response) {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                formData: {
                    title: response.data.item.bio,
                    bio: response.data.item.bio,
                    summary: response.data.item.summary,
                    headline: response.data.item.headline,
                    slug: response.data.item.slug,
                    statusId: response.data.item.statusId,
                    skills: response.data.item.skills,
                    primaryImage: response.data.item.primaryImage.imageUrl,
                }
            });
        }
    
        onGetByIdError(err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    
        componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    
            let currentPath = this.props.location.pathname;
            let previousPath = prevProps.location.pathname;
            console.log({currentPath, previousPath});
    
            let friendId = this.props.match.params.friendId;
            if(friendId && prevProps.match.params.friendId !== friendId){
                FriendService.getById(friendId)
                    .then(this.onGetByIdUpdateSuccess)
                    .catch(this.onGetByIdUpdateError);
            }
    
          }
    
          onGetByIdUpdateSuccess(response) {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                formData: {
                    title: response.data.item.bio,
                    bio: response.data.item.bio,
                    summary: response.data.item.summary,
                    headline: response.data.item.headline,
                    slug: response.data.item.slug,
                    statusId: response.data.item.statusId,
                    skills: response.data.item.skills,
                    primaryImage: response.data.item.primaryImage.imageUrl,
                }
            });
        }
    
        onGetByIdUpdateError(err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    
        render() {
            return(
                <Fade in={true} style={{ transitionDelay:'250ms'}}>
                        <div className="p-2 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
                    <h4 style={{
                        textAlign: 'center'
                    }}>Add a friend</h4>
                  <div className="container-fluid py-1">
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="inputTitle">Title:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputTitle" name="inputTitle" defaultValue={this.state.formData.title}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="inputBio">Bio:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputBio" name="inputBio" defaultValue={this.state.formData.bio}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="inputSummary">Summary:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputSummary" name="inputSummary" defaultValue={this.state.formData.summary}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="inputHeadline">Headline:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputHeadline" name="inputHeadline" defaultValue={this.state.formData.headline}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="inputSlug">Slug:</label>
                            <input type="url" className="form-control" id="inputSlug" name="inputSlug" defaultValue={this.state.formData.slug}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label htmlFor="statusId">Status Id</label>
                            <select name="statusId" id="statusId" className="form-control" onChange={this.onFormFieldChanged} value={this.state.formData.statusId}>
                            <option value="">Select Id Status</option>
                            <option value="1">NotSet</option>
                            <option value="2">Active</option>
                            <option value="3">Deleted</option>
                            <option value="4">Flagged</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="inputSkills">Skills</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputSkills" name="inputSkills" defaultValue={this.state.formData.skills}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="inputPrimaryImg">Primary Image:</label>
                            <input type="url" className="form-control" id="inputPrimaryImg" name="inputPrimaryImg" defaultValue={this.state.formData.primaryImage}></input>
                        </div>
                            <button id="register" type="button" className="btn btn-primary mr-3 m-3 mb-1" onClick={this.props.submit}>Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Fade>
                
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default AddFriend;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Here is what I did...

```
import React from "react";
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import * as FriendService from "../services/FriendService";

class AddFriend extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            formData: {
                title: "",
                bio: "",
                summary: "",
                headline: "",
                slug: "",
                statusId: "",
                skills: "",
                primaryImage: "",
            }
        };

        this.onGetByIdSuccess = this.onGetByIdSuccess.bind(this);
        this.onGetByIdUpdateSuccess = this.onGetByIdSuccess.bind(this);
        this.onFormFieldChanged = this.onFormFieldChanged.bind(this);
    }

    onFormFieldChanged = (e) => {
        let currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
        let newValue = currentTarget.value;
        let inputName = currentTarget.name;

        console.log({currentTarget, newValue});
        
        this.setState(() => {
            let formData = {...this.state.formData};
            formData[inputName] = newValue;
            if(formData.statusId === "1"){
                formData.statusId = "NotSet";
            }
            if(formData.statusId === "2"){
                formData.statusId = "Active";
            }
            if(formData.statusId === "3"){
                formData.statusId = "Deleted";
            }
            if(formData.statusId === "4"){
                formData.statusId = "Flagged";
            }
            return {formData};
        });
    };

    onSubmitClicked = () => {
        const data = {...this.state.formData};
        let friendId = this.props.match.params.friendId;
        console.log(data);
        if(!friendId) {
            FriendService.add(data)
                .then(this.onAddFriendSuccess)
                .catch(this.onAddFriendError);
        }
        else {
            FriendService.update(friendId)
                .then(this.onUpdateFriendSuccess)
                .catch(this.onUpdateFriendError);
        }
    };

    onAddFriendSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }

    onAddFriendError(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    onUpdateFriendSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }

    onUpdateFriendError(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        let friendId = this.props.match.params.friendId;
        console.log("ComponentDidMount", {friendId});

        if(friendId){

            FriendService.getById(friendId)
                .then(this.onGetByIdSuccess)
                .catch(this.onGetByIdError);
        }
    }

    onGetByIdSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            formData: {
                title: response.data.item.bio,
                bio: response.data.item.bio,
                summary: response.data.item.summary,
                headline: response.data.item.headline,
                slug: response.data.item.slug,
                statusId: response.data.item.statusId,
                skills: response.data.item.skills,
                primaryImage: response.data.item.primaryImage.imageUrl,
            }
        });
    }

    onGetByIdError(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

        let currentPath = this.props.location.pathname;
        let previousPath = prevProps.location.pathname;
        console.log({currentPath, previousPath});

        let friendId = this.props.match.params.friendId;
        if(friendId && prevProps.match.params.friendId !== friendId){
            FriendService.getById(friendId)
                .then(this.onGetByIdUpdateSuccess)
                .catch(this.onGetByIdUpdateError);
        }

      }

      onGetByIdUpdateSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            formData: {
                title: response.data.item.bio,
                bio: response.data.item.bio,
                summary: response.data.item.summary,
                headline: response.data.item.headline,
                slug: response.data.item.slug,
                statusId: response.data.item.statusId,
                skills: response.data.item.skills,
                primaryImage: response.data.item.primaryImage.imageUrl,
            }
        });
    }

    onGetByIdUpdateError(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Fade in={true} style={{ transitionDelay:'250ms'}}>
                    <div className="p-2 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
                <h4 style={{
                    textAlign: 'center'
                }}>Add a friend</h4>
              <div className="container-fluid py-1">
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputTitle">Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputTitle" name="inputTitle" defaultValue={this.state.formData.title}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputBio">Bio:</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputBio" name="inputBio" defaultValue={this.state.formData.bio}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputSummary">Summary:</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputSummary" name="inputSummary" defaultValue={this.state.formData.summary}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputHeadline">Headline:</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputHeadline" name="inputHeadline" defaultValue={this.state.formData.headline}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputSlug">Slug:</label>
                        <input type="url" className="form-control" id="inputSlug" name="inputSlug" defaultValue={this.state.formData.slug}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label htmlFor="statusId">Status Id</label>
                        <select name="statusId" id="statusId" className="form-control" onChange={this.onFormFieldChanged} value={this.state.formData.statusId}>
                        <option value="">{this.state.formData.statusId}</option>
                        <option value="1">NotSet</option>
                        <option value="2">Active</option>
                        <option value="3">Deleted</option>
                        <option value="4">Flagged</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputSkills">Skills</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputSkills" name="inputSkills" defaultValue={this.state.formData.skills}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPrimaryImg">Primary Image:</label>
                        <input type="url" className="form-control" id="inputPrimaryImg" name="inputPrimaryImg" defaultValue={this.state.formData.primaryImage}></input>
                    </div>
                        <button id="register" type="button" className="btn btn-primary mr-3 m-3 mb-1" onClick={this.props.submit}>Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Fade>
            
        );
    }
}

export default AddFriend;
```